# classification with four classes by matlab

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a classification problem with four classes of input vector.The four classes are

```
A = [1 , 1; 1 ,2];
B = [2,2; -1,0];
C = [-1,-2;2,1];
D = [-1,-2; -1,-2];
```

I wan Implement this problem by Matlab, I Use this code :

```
 C = [-1,-2;2,1];
 A = [1 , 1; 1 ,2];
 B = [2,2; -1,0];
 D = [-1,-2; -1,-2];

 hold on
 grid on

 plot(A(1,:),A(2,:),'bs')
 plot(B(1,:),B(2,:),'r+')
 plot(C(1,:),C(2,:),'go')
 plot(D(1,:),D(2,:),'m*')
 a = [0 1]';
 b = [1 1]';
 c = [1 0]';
 d = [0 0]';
 P = [A B C D];

 T = [repmat(a,1,length(A)) repmat(b,1,length(B)) repmat(c,1,length(C))    repmat(d,1,length(D)) ];
 net = perceptron;
 E = 1;
 net.adaptParam.passes = 1;
 linehandle = plotpc(net.IW{1},net.b{1});
 n = 0;
 while (sse(E))
 n = n+1;
 [net,Y,E] = adapt(net,P,T);
 linehandle = plotpc(net.IW{1},net.b{1},linehandle);
 drawnow;
end
```

but My Code does'nt work I have No idea why, please Help me....

Comment: what does not work? what is your error? how does the result differ from your expected result?

Comment: while loop never finish!!

Comment: your while loop is dependent on the error flag `E` which is the output of the adapt function. But you never change its inputs, so the while loop is doing the same over and over.

Comment: i change net, please help me .., how??

Comment: I'm not familiar with neural networks, so I can't tell you where the error is, just where you could search for it. Insert cell breaks `%%` before and after your function call `[net,Y,E] = adapt(net,P,T);
` - then you can execute just these section, therefore you can see the results for every single iteration. Does `E` change? I further guess that `sse(E)` ist not correct, i'd rather use `~E`, also `sse` actually requires more than one input argument, not just `E`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested by thewaywewalk, the trouble is your `while`-loop and the fact that you do not provide an adequate check for the statement you wish to evaluate.
Replace your `while`-statement with these two lines:

```
ACCEPTABLE_ERROR = 3.0;
while (sse(E)>ACCEPTABLE_ERROR)
```

And you should see your script terminate after three iterations. You can play with the `ACCEPTABLE_ERROR` variable to check which solution works best for you. If you set it too small, your while loop will not exit, because the statement will not be false.

---

An explanation to your original `while`-statement:
All you ever evaluated if `sse(e)` returned a results - which it did in each case. That's why it never stopped.

---

To the question of `sse` requires more than one input argument:
That depends on what input arguments you provide.
[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/sse.html) says:

> perf = sse(net,t,y,ew) takes these input arguments and optional function parameters,
>
> net: Neural network
>   t: Matrix or cell array of target vectors
>   y: Matrix or cell array of output vectors
>   ew: Error weights (default = {1})
>
> and returns the sum squared error.

However, it is not necessary, to provide the error weights, `ew`, as the source code reveals:

> Only the first three arguments are required. The default error weight is {1}, which weights the importance of all targets equally.

In your case you *should*, based on the documentation, call `sse` like this:

```
sse(net,T,Y)
```

Without being mentioned in the documentation (or I haven't found it), this is equivalent to what you have done, by providing simply the network errors, `E` as provided from `adapt`:

```
sse(E)
```

Both give the same results.

Comment: @user2853483 Was this answer helpful to you? If so, consider accepting it. If not, please comment on remaining issues.